# Error while changing data model schema. Cannot de-serialize Database. The JSON input is not properly formed. Check path '', line 0, position 0."

Tags: python, json, error-handling, powerbi, load

I was trying to make some changes to the the datamodel schema in powerbi pbit file. I am using python to kind of automate the entire process (as there are lot of dashboards to be updated). Steps followed are:

1. importing datamodel using from dax_extract import read_data_model_schema.
2. update the datasource in partitions
3. load back(save) the datamodel file to the pbit file.

I was able to import and update the file. After saving the new datamodel inside pbit file, when I open, it is giving me an error of "Cannot de-serialize Database. The JSON input is not properly formed. Check path '', line 0, position 0."
I am pretty sure that the changes made on file are correct. Can someone tell me why this happens?

Comment: please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before commenting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: The encoding of the file was to blame in my case.

I was doing something similar (all be it in C#) and had the same very unhelpful error.

Using `Notepad++`, I opened my original `model.bim` file and could see the encoding of the file was `UTF-8`.

Then I opened the file I modified with my script and saw that the encoding was `UTF-8-BOM`.

Finally, after converting the file back to `UTF-8` (you can do that with Notepad++) and saving it I was able to open the modified `.pbip` report with PowerBI Desktop.